# Prevent items from moving around in the DOM with CSS when other elements get displayed

Tags: css, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/10002/

I'm trying to keep `2A` where it is, without moving when `1A` or `1B` are introduced.  I've tried playing with position and display properties but can't figure out how to keep `2A` right where it is without moving.

CSS:

```
.first {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;

}
.second {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    left: 24px;
}
.container {
    width: 170px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>title:</p>
    <input> 
        <!-- ko if: showTop -->
    <span data-bind="if: showFirst">
          <i class="first">1A</i>
    </span>
    <span data-bind="if: !showFirst()">
           <i class="first">1B</i>
    </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
     <span data-bind="if: showSecond">
           <i class="second">2A</i>
    </span>

    <button data-bind="click: toggleFirst">toggle 1 value</button>
    <button data-bind="click: toggleFirstVisibility">toggle 1 visibility</button>
    <p data-bind="text: showFirst"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: showSecond"></p>
</div>
```

How can I make `2A` stay put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute position :

```
.first {      
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 160px;

}
.second {
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
}
.container {
    width: 170px;
}
```

[**see fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/10003/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without absolute positioning?  other elements in the container may change size so I want to somehow position relative to the parent element :/

Comment: scratch that - I got it working with your code by setting the parent element to position: relative.  Thanks :)

Comment: It is pointless to apply a `float` and a `position: absolute` (or `fixed`) on an element at the same time. The `position` overrides any `float` behavior.